# Line coverage between SonarQube and Jacoco is different

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, jacoco

i have the problem that in SonarQube v6.7 the line coverage is lower than in jacoco report.

When I'm opening sonar my class file has a lot of uncovered lines. When opening the jacoco report, it shows me that these lines are covered.

I'm using the gradle plugin. (v2.6)

Any ideas what can be the issue?

Comment: Could you be more specific ? Project structure ? Are uncovered lines have a common feature ?

Comment: sonar configuration, maybe you exclude files from coverate

Answer (score 0):

OK, had found the solution in a different thread.

Just added into the build.gradle

```
subprojects {
tasks.withType(Test) {
    // redirect all coverage data to one file
    // ... needs cleaning the data prior to the build to avoid accumulating coverage data of different runs.
    // see `task cleanJacoco`
    jacoco {
//            destinationFile = file("$rootProject.buildDir/jacoco/${project.name}.exec")
        destinationFile = file("$rootProject.buildDir/jacoco/test.exec")
    }
}

task cleanJacoco(dependsOn: 'clean') {  delete "$buildDir/jacoco" }
```

}